# Java Keccak 256 hashing implementation of multiple inputs

Tags: evm, cryptography, java, keccak

What's the best way to achieve the equivalent hashing in Java as below in Solidity?
`keccak256(abi.encodePacked(arg1,arg2,...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to use StringBuilder to append the strings as arguments for kaccak256, then to use library web3j to use sha3 method.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(arg1);
    sb.append(arg2);
    sb.append(arg3);
    byte[] hash = Hash.sha3(Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(String.valueOf(sb)));
```